# Prefix search using BinarySearch

Tags: java

Using prefix string i need to display all possible string from ArrayList using BinarySearch. Is it possible tell me the wright way.

```
BinarySearch(myList, SearchString);
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to find all strings in an `ArrayList` that start with a given prefix? And that you need to use a binary search to do so? I'm not sure I understand the requirements.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

To every `String` *`prefix`* and non-empty `String` *`suffix`* applies `prefix < prefix+suffix`.

So you can use [`Collections.<String>binarySearch(List<String>,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) to search for the position of *`prefix`*. Of course, the existence or absence of the prefix does not say anything about the existence or absence of the `prefix+suffix` `String`s. So if the index is negative, convert it using `-index-1` and check that position whether it is equal to the list’s size (in this case no prefixed `String` was found) or if the `String` at that index has the prefix. If the index was not negative, i.e. *`prefix`* without a suffix was found you have to decide whether to include `String`s with empty suffix or not. Since `binarySearch` will return an arbitrary index in the case of multiple occurrences you have to use the returned index to go linearly to the first occurrence, either backward or forward depending on your decision whether *`prefix`* without a suffix shall be included or not.

Once you have the first position you could use `binarySearch` again to find the end of all prefixed `String`s by searching for the smallest `String` which is greater than any prefixed `String`. This `String` can be constructed by incrementing the last character of the prefix by one. Here again it doesn’t matter whether that `String` is really there, it just gives us the delimiter for the range of prefixed `String`s. So you will convert negative values using `-index-1` and have the first index of a `String` without the prefix; it will be the size of the list if no such `String` exists.

```
public static List<String> findAllPrefixed(
  List<String> list, String prefix, boolean includeEmptySuffixed)
{
  int first=Collections.binarySearch(list, prefix);
  if(first<0)
  {
    first=-first-1;
    if(first==list.size() || !list.get(first).startsWith(prefix))
      return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  else
  {
    if(includeEmptySuffixed)
      while(first>0 && list.get(first-1).equals(prefix)) first--;
    else
    {
      do first++; while(first<list.size() && list.get(first).equals(prefix));
      if(first==list.size() || !list.get(first).startsWith(prefix))
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
  }
// the conditional is just a small optimization
  List<String> notSmaller=first>0? list.subList(first, list.size()): list;
  final int p = prefix.length()-1;
  if(p<0) return notSmaller;//empty prefix, there are no larger values
  final String after=prefix.substring(0, p)+(char)(prefix.charAt(p)+1);

  int last=Collections.binarySearch(notSmaller, after);
  if(last<0) last=-last-1;
// could just do notSmaller.subList(0,last); but this here reduces heap usage
  return last==notSmaller.size()? notSmaller: list.subList(first, first+last);
}
```